# How does proxy server bypass the default networkig behaviour?

Tags: windows, proxy

May be this is a silly/odd question but I want to know how exactly internally a proxy connection works on Windows OS. let me explain.

We have servers in a data center where there is no direct internet access but one of the servers does need internet access for which a proxy is configured. I want to know how exactly it works (routing-wise) when connecting to the internet. My understanding is that without proxy the normal behaviour of the TCP/IP stack is to go through default gateway but since in data center it isn't routed outside the network, I am assuming this proxy is doing the Default Gateway's equivalent role on this particular server.

Could you explain how it works underneath the surface? Sorry, if the question is too stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a proxy server, your TCP/IP connection goes straight to the proxy server. The proxy server then does the request out onto the internet. If the proxy server is on the same subnet, you don't even need a default gateway set if you just want to allow http/https access. If the proxy server is on another subnet, a route (typically the default route/gateway) needs to be configured to be able to access the proxy server. The proxy server should have a gateway set up so it can communicate with servers out on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean this proxy server takes over the role of Default gateway (from the OS point of view) for this internet connection?

Comment: From a OS point of view, no. From a web browser point of view, yes.